# No nonfinal states in NFA

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

I know that if there are no non-final states in DFA then the language accepted is $\Sigma^*$.

What will happen if there are no non-final states in an NFA? Can we say it also accepts $\Sigma^*$? Can there be an NFA with no non-final states whose minimal NFA has some non-final state?

---

Oh , no nonfinal states means all are final states. So DFA - all final states means every string gets accepted. So language is $\sum^*$. For NFA, it need not be $\sum^*$. Please correct me if i am wrong here. Other case --> If there are no final states(all non-final states) means in DFA, language accepted is empty language. In case of NFA with no final state means empty language right?

[image: nfa example]

Comment: Do you know why a DFA with no non-final states accepts $\Sigma^*$? See if the same argument works in your case.

Comment: I don't see where minimal automata enter the picture. The definition of the language accepted by a DFA/NFA doesn't involve them.

Comment: sir please have a look at my edited part.

Comment: Can you give an example of an NFA with no non-final states whose language is not everything?

Comment: sir please see above

Comment: Yes, seems fine.

Comment: sir is this for other case right?Other case --> If there are no final states(all non-final states) means in DFA, language accepted is empty language. In case of NFA with no final state means empty language right?

Comment: I think I gave you enough help.

Comment: ok tq sir........

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question was solved by OP.

Comment: ok. np.please go ahead........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine an NFA with a single state, which is final/accepting. It has no edges.

This NFA accepts the language $\{\varepsilon\}$—that is, only the empty string. If it is given a non-empty string, it looks for appropriate edges leading away from the starting state, finds none, and fails.